# batik - id-attribute occurs twice in saved document

Tags: java, svg, batik

I use Batik two load one svg-document and add an element form another
document to it, but the id-attribute occurs in the saved document in some attributes now 
twice. So when I'am trying to open the saved document with Inkscape, it just shows an error,
that it couldn't open the file. By deleting some of the ids manually, the file now can be open with Inkscape.

Thank you very much for your help.

...

```
try {
 // Load the basic symbol
 String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
 SAXSVGDocumentFactory f = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
 Document documentBasicSymbol = f.createSVGDocument(imgFileBasicSymbol.toURI().toString());


 // Set the fill color of the basic symbol to symbolColor
 Element element = documentBasicSymbol.getElementById("basic_symbol");
 setSymbolFillColor(element, symbolColor);


 // Load the supplementary symbol
 Document documentSupplemtarySymbol =    
f.createDocument(imgFileSupplementarySymbol.toURI().toString());

// Add it to the basic symbol:
Node nodeSupplementarySymbol = documentBasicSymbol.importNode(documentSupplemtarySymbol.getElementById("supplementary_symbol"), true);
       documentBasicSymbol.getDocumentElement().appendChild(nodeSupplementarySymbol);

storeDocument(documentBasicSymbol, "SuppElementZuBasic.svg");
```

...

part of the document:

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" zoomAndPan="magnify"
contentStyleType="text/css" id="svg2" height="100"
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg2" version="1.2">
  <g id="layer1" id="layer1"
  transform="translate(1.4982643,1.4982643)">
    <rect x="64.599998" y="29.674999" width="67.803474"
    style="fill:blue;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.0965271;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
    height="37.653473" id="basic_symbol" id="basic_symbol" />
  </g>
  <path d="m 116.10938,37.703125 0,10.8125 -47.531255,0 0,2.40625 47.531255,0 0,4.5 0,0.59375 0.90625,0.28125 13.49999,6 0.3125,-0.875 0.59375,-0.90625 -13.21874,-5.75 0,-17.0625 -2.09375,0 z"
  id="supplementary_symbol"
  style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
  id="supplementary_symbol" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use the `id`, you might try the [3 argument importNode](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/dom/AbstractDocument.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) with the third value (`trimIds`) set to `true`.

Other than that, the only other thing I can think of is to walk the DOM of your additional element and adjust/remove the ids.

It's probably work filing a [bug against Batik](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&bug_status=__open__&product=Batik). It really should not let you generate illegal xml.